# Qual è il significato di "sfilaccio" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> C’erano state le lunghe conversazioni con Franco e quelle occasionali con Mariarosa, ormai confuse dentro un unico **sfilaccio** di vapore (*il mondo è profondamente ingiusto e bisogna cambiarlo, ma sia la coesistenza pacifica tra l’imperialismo americano e le burocrazie staliniste, sia le politiche riformistiche dei partiti operai europei e specialmente italiani, puntano a tenere il proletariato in un attendismo subalterno che getta acqua sul fuoco della rivoluzione, con la conseguenza che se vince lo stallo mondiale, se vince la socialdemocrazia, sarà il capitale a trionfare nei secoli e la classe operaia diventerà preda della coazione al consumo*).

Ho cercato il significato di "sfilaccio", ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una stoffa o un cavo può *sfilacciarsi*; i fili che escono dalla loro posizione prevista sono *sfilacci* o *sfilacciature*.

L'uso nel passo citato è figurato e ora dovresti aver capito il significato.

Dalle mie parti è piuttosto nota una specialità alimentare, gli *sfilacci di cavallo*: carne di cavallo essiccata e poi ridotta appunto a sfilacci che si mangiano conditi con olio e parmigiano.

[image]

Comment: @Charo OT Come è _Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta_?

Comment: @mario: *L'amica geniale* e *Storia del nuovo cognome* mi sono piaciuti. Succede che, dopo averli finiti, si ha voglia di vedere come continua la storia di Lila e Lenù, quindi adesso sto leggendo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta*.